# How to insert,Delete,Edit record in MYSQL database using Details View in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am new in asp net .

I wanted to is there any way to insert, delete and edit rows using details view directly

by a string.

I am using these connection string for connecting mysql database

```
server=localhost;User Id=root;password=test;database=mydatabase
```

when I use mdf file I see the insert, delete and edit option, but when I look the options by using directly connection string I can't see it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put that connection string in your web.config (look up 'connectionstrings').  And then use an objectdatasource.  They can connect to the MySQL database.

However, you typically do not want to put select/insert/delete statements in your code and will want to write procedures for those.